# How to send processed data from asp.net web page to Android

Tags: android, html, asp.net, android-webview

I have a web site that I write it using Asp.NET and SQL Server. In SQL Server I have a table that I save my user's UserName and thier Password and in the web I get UserName and Password From Url (using queryString), and do registration. Also I have an Android app that I want to connect to that web page programaticly, but I don't know how get the result of registration that come from the web to my app.

I mean after I send the username and password from Android app to the web and my web check the registration of my username and password, how can I get the result of registration in Android app?

Consider I want to set the text of a textview to "ok" if registered and set the text of it to "no" if not registered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `WebView` to navigate to the web site, passing the correct fileds in the URL string, and then interpret the resulting page of the website.

Have a look at the official page of **WebView**:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

And try to **access the HTML** of the page:

http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/

So you can read the resulting HTML and get whatever you want form it. I suggest you to create a lightweight web page of your site specifically for be interpreted by your App.

Now, passing username/password in the URL address is never good. If you don't use SSL a **Man in the middle** attack is always a potential security problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: but i still have problem. you said that read the resulting html , what do you mean by that , how can i create a result as html in asp.net that i can get it in my android app . can you explain more ?

Comment: 1° from app you create the url with user id and password, 2° open the url with the webview (hidden), 3° get the resulting html page from your site. Right?

Comment: You create a page in asp, named for example app_user_check.aspx, you call it from the app like app_user_check.aspx?id=name&pw=1234. The server interpret the url, check for credentials and then write using Response.write() a string like "OK" or "FAILED".

Comment: You app using WebView look into the page result and read "OK" or "FAILED"